# C# Progress Counter sometimes not incrementing to expected value?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I am testing the validity of a list proxies.  Every time a proxy is tested, I am incrementing a property of type int named Progress.  If I test a list of 100 proxies, sometimes Progress will equal 100 when all tasks have completed, but sometimes it will not be that expected value of 100, but rather 97 or 98 (it varies).

```
public class ProxyTester
{
    public int Progress { get; set; }

    public async Task Start(List<Proxy> proxies, List<ProxyJudge> judges, List<ProxyTest> tests = null, PauseOrCancelToken pct = null, int maxConcurrency = 100)
    {
        if (tests == null)
        {
            tests = new List<ProxyTest>();
        }

        this.Progress = 0;

        //Get external IP to check if proxy is anonymous.
        var publicIp = await WebUtility.GetPublicIP();

        //Validate proxy judges.
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency);

        foreach (var judge in judges)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                judge.IsValid = await judge.TestValidityAsync();
                if (pct != null) { await pct.PauseOrCancelIfRequested(); }
                semaphore.Release();
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var validJudges = from judge in judges
                            where judge.IsValid
                            select judge;

        if (validJudges.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("No valid judges loaded.");
        }

        //Validate proxy tests.
        tasks.Clear();
        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                test.IsValid = await test.TestValidityAsync();
                if (pct != null) { await pct.PauseOrCancelIfRequested(); }
                semaphore.Release();
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var validTests = from test in tests
                            where test.IsValid
                            select test;

        //Test proxies with a random, valid proxy judge.  If valid, test with all valid proxy tests.
        tasks.Clear();

        foreach (var proxy in proxies)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                proxy.IsValid = await proxy.TestValidityAsync(validJudges.ElementAt(RandomUtility.GetRandomInt(0, validJudges.Count())));
                this.Progress++;
                Console.WriteLine(this.Progress + " / " + proxies.Count);
                if (pct != null) { await pct.PauseOrCancelIfRequested(); }
                semaphore.Release();
                if (proxy.IsValid)
                {
                    proxy.TestedSites.AddRange(validTests);
                    var childTasks = new List<Task>();
                    foreach (var test in validTests)
                    {
                        childTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                            proxy.TestedSites.ElementAt(proxy.TestedSites.IndexOf(test)).IsValid = await proxy.TestValidityAsync(test);
                            if (pct != null) { await pct.PauseOrCancelIfRequested(); }
                            semaphore.Release();
                        }));
                    }

                    await Task.WhenAll(childTasks);
                }
            }));
        }


        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a backing field marked `volatile` and `Interlocked.Increment` to update it from multiple threads.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks Ron, I will try that solution in a minute.

Comment: @RonBeyer That solved the problem.  Would +1 you again if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that updates for variables from multiple threads are not atomic. In order for multiple threads to update that variable, you need to mark it as `volatile` and use a synchronization method like `Interlocked.Increment`.

Since you have to pass the variable by `ref`, you need to create a backing field:

```
private volatile int _progress = 0;
public int Progress => _progress;
```

Then, instead of

```
this.Progress++;
```

You would change it to an interlocked call:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _progress);
```

Now multiple threads can update this without risk of collision. The issue you were running into was that one thread would read the value and two threads would update it, overwriting some of the updates. This is why it seems "random", it depends on timing which ones and how many get overwritten.